# GridView input not committed

Tags: c#, .net, devexpress

I have a problem with a DataGridView (DevExpress) when clicking outside the GridView on another component. The changed value resets to default and commits, which is not as intended.

```
//Designer:
this.grdSokande.Leave += new System.EventHandler(this.grdSokandeNew_Leave);

//Event in codebehind
private void grdSokandeNew_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e){
  SokandeBindingSource.EndEdit();
}
```

If I put a breakpoint i can see that the value flips back to default when exiting GridView.
I have looked at DirtyState but DevExpress seems not to have an equivalent function.

Comment: Mark answer as "Accepted" if you got a solution for the problem.

Comment: same question from same user [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12706934/datagridview-resets-cellvalue-without-committing-when-leaving-control)

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the values in the active row/cell before issuing an EndEdit()

Comment: Does this mean that I have to create an event for the cells?

Comment: No, it is usually enough to do a gridView1.PostEditor();